# How to determine which Latest stable Python3.x suits best for HDP3.1.5 and RHEL7.9

Tags: python-3.x, hadoop, pyspark, rhel7, hdp

We are currently using Python2.7 with HDP3.1.5 (PySpark | Spark2.3) and RHEL 7.9.
We are planning to upgrade to Python3.x as Python2.7 support has ended.

If anyone could please help with determining the latest stable Python3.x? version that will best suit or compatible with HDP3.1.5 (Spark2.3) and RHEL 7.9?
OR
Let me know necessary steps I should follow to determine the best stable Python3.x? version for our HDP stack?

Thanks,
PB

Comment: Any version between 3.6-3.9 should work.

Answer (score 1):

The max Python version supported is 2.7.5, Python Version 3.x is not supported as it will create conflict with the versions shipped (HDP3.1.5 + Ambari2.7.5).

Python3 support is not on the road map of HDP 3x and even for Ambari.
This is something which may be done in future to make Python3 as the default for the OS Cloudera supports.